# I can't find the general solution (Second Order Linear Equations)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the general solution to:

y'' + 4y = t^2 + 7e^t

The actual problem wants me to find the initial value problem with y(0) = 0 and y'(0) = 2 but I'm confident that I can find the IVP after finding the general solution.

What I DO need help with is this:

I'm trying to set Y(t) = At^2 + Bt + C and solving for A, B, and C for a specific solution but I find two different values for A.  (1/4, and 0).

I did solve for e^t and found the answer to be 7/5.

It's t^2's answer that I'm stumped on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the characteristic equation is
$m^2+4=0$ 
$m=\pm2 i$
$$y_c=C_1\cos2 t+C_2\sin2 t$$
$$y_p=At^2+Bt+C+De^t$$
$$y'_p=2At+B+De^t$$
$$y''_p=2A+De^t$$
substitute in the original equation
$$2A+De^t+4At^2+4Bt+4C+4De^t=t^2+7e^t$$
so
$$A=1/4$$
$$B=0$$
$$C=-1/8$$
$$D=7/5$$
the general solution is
$$y=C_1\cos2 t+C_2\sin2 t+t^2/4-1/8+7/5e^t$$

Comment: But 2A doesn't have a counter part on the right side.  With you answers, there should be a 1/2 on the right side of the equation.

Comment: @JinLee $2A+4C=0$

Comment: I am sorry, that is correct.  Thank you for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic equation is $r^2 + 4  = 0$, so you get $y_h = c_1 \cos (2 t)+ c_2 \sin(2 t) $. Now, use the method of undetermined coefficients to make some guesses to the general solution: If you plug in $y_3 = c_3 e^t$, you'll get $y_3''+ 4 y_3 = 5 c_3 e^t$, so having $c_3 = \frac{7}{5}$ gives the $e^t$ on the right. Now, for the $t^2$, since you have a quadratic, you should guess $y_4 = a t^2 + bt + c$. Then, $y_4 '' + 4 y_4 = 2a + 4 (a t^2 + bt + c) = 4a t^2 + bt + c+2a$. Matching this to $t^2$ gives $a=\frac{1}{4}, b=0, c=-1/8$.

Thus, your solution is $y = c_1 \cos (2t) + c_2 \sin(2t)  + \frac{7}{5} e^t + \frac{1}{4} t^2-1/8$.

Comment: I think there is a wrong in your characteristic equation

Comment: Indeed, just fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: How did you get from 2a+4(at^2+bt+c) to 6at^2+bt+c?  I don't see any like terms.

Comment: you can use the Wronskian method to solve them

Comment: the coefficient of $t^2$  should be $1/4$ and there is another coefficient not there in your solution